# ABC Tracing in Android Programming

Tags: java, android

I want to make an **Alphabet Letters Tracing** game for kids, I don't have that much idea where to start and what library to use how to make it trace. I have basic knowledge about android java programming this project is for personal use and to expand my knowledge on creating android apps.
Is there any 3rd party software?
THANK YOU very much in advance.

Comment: What does this tracing means? Can you please explain more about it?

Comment: for children how they will write the letter A, there will be a dashed line that will follow the path of A, its like from how we learn writing it on a piece of paper

Comment: She is asking for references  to visualization libraries in android. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an `ImageView` holding the letter image with dashed lines, then create for example `20` more images with each dashed line being filled in with the letters colour. Setting up an xml `DrawableAnimation` you could sequence through the images of the lines being slowly filed in for them to trace. Although this may be the easiest way, it's not the smoothest, or most efficient. But gets the job done.

Comment: i would try this thank you..